# Configuring spring Batch tasks in Spring cloud data flow

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have created a project with 2 rest API that launches different Jobs. My project is connected to a MySql database. I would like to monitor both the Jobs in spring cloud data flow. Please help me out how we need to configure SCDF to MySql so that both the Jobs will be monitored. And additionally, i would like to know that how, if we launch the job by firing the API, whether our SCDF will monitor those Job Instance. If not, please let me know how we can do that.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Please take a moment to read the Spring Batch Admin to SCDF [migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch-admin/blob/master/MIGRATION.md#migrating-from-spring-batch-admin-to-spring-cloud-data-flow). It is a *requirement* that the jobs are wrapped with Spring Cloud Task programming model.

Once you have the batch-job wrapped as a Task, you can register them in SCDF to build Task/Batch pipelines using SCDF's DSL or the GUI.

As for the datasource, all you must have to make sure is that the same datasource is [shared](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_task_database_configuration) between SCDF and the batch-jobs. With this, SCDF's Dashboard will automatically list the jobs and its execution details.

Here are a few [examples](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-samples/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_task_batch) for your reference.

> And additionally, i would like to know that how, if we launch the job by firing the API, whether our SCDF will monitor those Job Instance

Assuming you're referring to SCDF's Task launch API *(e.g., a Scheduled trigger or by other means)*; if triggered, yes, the job executions will be captured in the database as far as SCDF and the batch-jobs share a common datasource as explained previously.